# Unexpected noise at low pass filtered output

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter

I am trying to capture and filter a PPG signal using a simple phototransistor and an IR led. I have hooked the emitter to a Bessel low pass filter so as to get rid of high frequency signals. Below is the full schematics:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7g9XV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> Cut-off freq: around 3.31Hz

I observed the signals on the oscilloscope and the signal at emitter seems fine (observable PPG signal with noise: at emitter (Yellow).) I am expecting the output: opamp out (Blue) to be a much cleaner version, but it is appearing noisy with no improvement:

[image]

the signal is fine until the non-inverting input of the opamp and is filtered due to the low pass configuration, Blue: at opamp(+); Yellow: at emitter

[image: Expected Output]

About a month ago, I had used the exact schematics and tested the circuit which worked straight away without any issues. Blue: at emitter; Yellow: at opamp out:

[image]

So far I have re-breadboarded the circuit, replaced parts, tried different power sources, but nothing is helping.

Comment: Trace the supply voltage.

Comment: I am powering via Arduino, Can see 5V on opamp Vcc

Comment: Show the full circuit and, unambiguously state the component values. Also show full screen o-scope shots and state which colour is which signal.

Comment: added the full circuit along with component values with color labeling, Pls do let me know if additional captures are required.

Comment: You have  PSU RF noise to gnd. Suppress that

Comment: The problem might be the lack of DC level at the emitter - it's pretty much undefined in your circuit. You'd do better with a proper bias circuit. This might be the difference between then and now. Unfortunately your scope shots are all AC coupled so this cannot be determined.

Comment: looks like AC line or switcher CM noise. Earth ground it or use a battery or RF cap 0Vdc to earth gnd and use AGC. Can't you tell?

Comment: Schematic does not show any decoupling caps

Comment: @Tony Yes I had tried with batteries, same response, It seems my probe is also picking up a lot of noise. i am using a USB osc, Though the laptop is running on batteries.

Comment: Thanks @Andy for suggestions, I will come up with a better circuit.